# What's the difference between internal spaces and extra dimensions?

Tags: differential-geometry, spacetime-dimensions

From a geometrical perspective, we attach a copy of our gauge groups (e.g. $U(1)$ to each point in spacetime. Since Lie groups are manifolds we can, therefore, imagine that there is a little circle, sphere etc. attached to each point.

**In what sense is this modern fiber bundle perspective different from the idea of extra dimensions?**

Comment: These would be better interprted as extra dimensions in phase space -- in classical mechanics, phase space is a fibre bundle (tangent bundle), but you would not consider that as "extra dimensions".

Comment: @Toffomat Sure, but I'm really curious if there is any way to make this a bit more precious. Intuitively, I think we all know well what counts as internal space. But I'm unsure how to formulate this distinction clearly

Comment: Extra dimensions show up in the metric tensor.